# UICollectionView image on cell memory warning

Tags: memory, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell

**im using Xcode 4.6.1, iOS SDK 6.1, ARC and Storyboards, testing device iphone 4S running 6.1.3**

I'm having a little trouble configuring a collectionviewcell containing pictures, there thing is when i try to add some custom pictures on the cell, the memory just jump directly by 30-40mb each picture, the picture are taking directly on the device camera and saved on documents directory, maybe you can help me with this.

here are the codes i use:

```
    --the code to load the images path on an array imagesArray
-(void) llenarArregloImagenes
{
imagesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSFileManager *fileMgr=[[NSFileManager alloc]init];
NSError * error = nil;
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)     lastObject];
//vemos cuantos objetos con la extension .jpg hay
NSArray *contenidoDirectorio=[fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
//FILTER THE JPG FILES
contenidoDirectorio = [contenidoDirectorio filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension ==[c] %@", @"jpg"]];
//para meter en el arrelo las imagenes
int indice=0;
if([contenidoDirectorio count]>0)
{
for(indice=0;indice<=[contenidoDirectorio count]-1;indice++)
{
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithString:[contenidoDirectorio objectAtIndex:indice]]];
    [imagesArray addObject:path];
}
}

    --end loading images
```

then i use this code to load the images on the collection view

```
--collection view code to add image to cell
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"Entra a las celdas");
static NSString *identificador=@"celdaImagen";
celdaImagen *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identificador forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
//myCell.imagen.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
//comprimir la imagen
//double compressionRatio=1;
//NSData *imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,compressionRatio);
//NSLog(@"tamano de la imagen %i",(imgData.length)/1024);
//UIImage *imagenRedimensionada=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
//
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //png o jpg
NSLog(@"tamano imagen %i",(imageData.length)/1024);
myCell.imagen.image=image;
return myCell;
}
--end of loading images
```

this is the code i use to save the image from the camera or from the camera roll, i must say i dont care if it is PNG or JPG i can use any.

```
--code to save image on documents file 
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.009); //png o jpg
        NSLog(@"tamano imagen %i",(imageData.length)/1024);
        NSFileManager *fileMgr=[[NSFileManager alloc]init];
        NSError * error = nil;
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)     lastObject];
        //vemos cuantos objetos con la extension .png hay
        NSArray *contenidoDirectorio=[fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
        //contenidoDirectorio = [contenidoDirectorio filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension ==[c] %@", @"mov"]];
        NSString *nombreArchivo=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imagen%i.jpg",[contenidoDirectorio count]] ;
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:nombreArchivo];
        //mostramos el contenido del archivo
        NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
        //guardamos el archivo
        [imageData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
        //volvemos a cargar los datos del collectionview
        [self llenarArregloImagenes];
        //metemos la ruta completa de la imagen
        //double compressionRatio=0.1;
        //NSData *imgData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,compressionRatio);
        //UIImage *imagenRedimensionada=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
        //
        //[imagesArray addObject:imagenRedimensionada];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        if (error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            return;
        }
}
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
{
    // Code here to support video if enabled
}
}
--end of code to save image
```

what is the best aproach to do an aplication like the camera roll, where i can see more than 6 images? maybe i'm saving them wrong or adding wrong to the collection view? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale down the image size in the method

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
         cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can use the category for `UIImage` available [here](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

Use the method

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailImage:(NSInteger)thumbnailSize
      transparentBorder:(NSUInteger)borderSize
           cornerRadius:(NSUInteger)cornerRadius
   interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality;
```

**Edit:**
1. Include the following files from the url http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

> - UIImage+Resize.h, UIImage+Resize.m
> - UIImage+RoundedCorner.h, UIImage+RoundedCorner.m
> - UIImage+Alpha.h, UIImage+Alpha.m

2.Import the `UIImage+Resize.h`.

3.Alter your method

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
         cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to look like the below

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Entra a las celdas");
    static NSString *identificador=@"celdaImagen";
    celdaImagen *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identificador forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //png o jpg
    NSLog(@"tamano imagen %i",(imageData.length)/1024);

    myCell.imagen.image=[image thumbnailImage:20 // This should the size of the view in collection view. example: myCell width is 20 and height is 20. 
                            transparentBorder:0
                                 cornerRadius:0
                         interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationMedium];
    return myCell;
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: can you pls be more specific how do i use that method?i have tried it and i'm kinda new at this, however i have noticed my memory is growing and never decrease, i can comeback to the "parent" controller, and once again join this view and the memory keeps building up, the memory is never released, am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: wow this actually helped me a lot, however may i ask you something else that has nothing to do with the image, the ARC removes the object once it is out of scope, or when is collected to the garbage? i'm having a little trouble finding out when an object is collected because i still see objects from the previous view. What exactly this code do? delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: UPDATE for everyone asking why is happening this, i found out the way the device saves the image directly from camera, it does something nasty and when it decompress the image you get memory leak every time, the memory is not free so i just recompile the image on it original size with previous library and everything works smooth.