# ALAsset Library + Document Directory images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have lots of images into my app documents library. i want to show thumbnail Images of the document directory images.

I am using following code.

```
UIImage *thumbImage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:strImagePath];
if (thumbImage) {
    [thubImageView setImage:thumbImage];
}
```

It Works for me but the problem is that application freeze and crash because of the memory warning.

i have tried the   [1]: https://github.com/SlaunchaMan/GCDExample "GCDExample" but i am getting the same result.

ALAsset library is used to get the thumbnail images. but i dont know how to use it with document directory images.

and is there any other way to show the thumbnail images without memory warning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which type of view do you use to show list of images ? UICollectionView, UITableView or anything else?

Comment: i am using UITableView..

Comment: You should only be loading the images which are actually visible on screen at that time. Also, you should consider saving thumbnail images to disk so you don't have to load full size images and downscale on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161755/uicollectionview-image-on-cell-memory-warning/17161872#17161872)

U can use the method

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailImage:(NSInteger)thumbnailSize
      transparentBorder:(NSUInteger)borderSize
           cornerRadius:(NSUInteger)cornerRadius
   interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality;
```

for creating thumbnail images. `UIImage` category available [here](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code it is pretty difficult to answer this question more exactly, but the general solution to this problem is to lazily load the images you need as the table cells are displayed, and to make sure that the images are sufficiently small to hold in memory.

The provided [GCDExample](https://github.com/SlaunchaMan/GCDExample) does this using a global GCD queue. I would not recommend this approach, using concurrent queues couple with I/O can cause unexpected thread explosion. See this excellent [Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-09-25-gcd-practicum.html) article for a very detailed analysis. Using a serial GCD queue is a more sensible approach here.

Answer (score 0):

Make all images thumb image of any size for ex: 80x80 in temp directory use them in your required program area then remember to delete those temp directory in the case of done with your task.

This category implementation code would help you:

```
#import "UIImage+Resize.h"
@implementation UIImage (ResizeCategory)

-(UIImage*)resizedImageToSize:(CGSize)dstSize
{
    CGImageRef imgRef = self.CGImage;
    // the below values are regardless of orientation : for UIImages from Camera, width>height (landscape)
    CGSize  srcSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef)); // not equivalent to self.size (which is dependant on the imageOrientation)!

    CGFloat scaleRatio = dstSize.width / srcSize.width;

    UIImageOrientation orient = self.imageOrientation;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    switch(orient) {

        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.width, srcSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, srcSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.height, srcSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6  
            dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, srcSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI_2);
            break; 

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7  
            dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8  
            dstSize = CGSizeMake(dstSize.height, dstSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(srcSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;  

        default:  
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];  


    }  

    // The actual resize: draw the image on a new context, applying a transform matrix

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(dstSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -srcSize.height, 0);
    } else {  
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -srcSize.height);
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    // we use srcSize (and not dstSize) as the size to specify is in user space (and we use the CTM to apply a scaleRatio)
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, srcSize.width, srcSize.height), imgRef);
    UIImage* resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resizedImage;}

-(UIImage*)resizedImageToFitInSize:(CGSize)boundingSize scaleIfSmaller:(BOOL)scale
{
    // get the image size (independant of imageOrientation)
    CGImageRef imgRef = self.CGImage;
    CGSize srcSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef)); // not equivalent to self.size (which depends on the imageOrientation)!

    // adjust boundingSize to make it independant on imageOrientation too for farther computations
    UIImageOrientation orient = self.imageOrientation;  
    switch (orient) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            boundingSize = CGSizeMake(boundingSize.height, boundingSize.width);
            break;
        default:
            // NOP
            break;
    }

    // Compute the target CGRect in order to keep aspect-ratio
    CGSize dstSize;

    if ( !scale && (srcSize.width < boundingSize.width) && (srcSize.height < boundingSize.height) ) {
        ////NSLog(@"Image is smaller, and we asked not to scale it in this case (scaleIfSmaller:NO)");
        dstSize = srcSize; // no resize (we could directly return 'self' here, but we draw the image anyway to take image orientation into account)
    } else {        
        CGFloat wRatio = boundingSize.width / srcSize.width;
        CGFloat hRatio = boundingSize.height / srcSize.height;

        if (wRatio < hRatio) {
            ////NSLog(@"Width imposed, Height scaled ; ratio = %f",wRatio);
            dstSize = CGSizeMake(boundingSize.width, srcSize.height * wRatio);
        } else {
            ////NSLog(@"Height imposed, Width scaled ; ratio = %f",hRatio);
            dstSize = CGSizeMake(srcSize.width * hRatio, boundingSize.height);
        }
    }

    return [self resizedImageToSize:dstSize];
}

@end
```

memory issues would be resolved automatically.