# App crashes due to memory error when images are held in a collection view from core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, uicollectionview

I am adding images to a collection view from core data that takes in images from a uiimagepicker. However, when I load more than 6 images into my app, it takes up most of the memory and sometimes crashes. I am not doing anything to the images except fetching them and putting them straight into the collection view in cells that have 100x100 image views. Does anyone know what I can do to reduce the memory and make the app not crash?

Code snippets:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _fetchedObjects.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        PhotosCollectionViewCell * cell = (PhotosCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSManagedObject *object = [_fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.cellImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[object valueForKey:@"image"]];
        return cell;
}
```

Other class:

```
    Photo * photoEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
    NSError * error;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image);
    photoEntity.name = _nameField.text;
    photoEntity.image = imageData;
    photoEntity.imagedescription = _descriptionField.text;
    if (![_context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"There was a save error:%@",error);
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks

Comment: Whats the stored image size? If the image view is 100 x 100, u need to reduce the size of the image when displaying.

Comment: @iCoder I want to still keep a higher resolution for when you click on the image though. Is it possible to have both?

Comment: I have answered the same question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161755/uicollectionview-image-on-cell-memory-warning/17161872#17161872


Hope this helps!

Comment: Which format are your images and what are their sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate high-resolution image from the preview you use in the collection view.

Just extract the high-resolution data to a separate entity behind the relationship from `Photo` object. Let’s call this second entity `ImageData`. It will have a single attribute `imageData` with option “Allows external storage” checked. `Photo` will have a relationship to `ImageData` and `ImageData` will have an inverse relationship to `Photo`.

`Photo` will have a small version of the image. With the resolution just enough for the cells. It also doesn’t hurt to check “Allows external storage for it” so that Core Data would decide where to store it.

Now when you fetch your `Photo` objects for the collection view, you’ll load only small version of images. The relationship itself to the `ImageData` will be fault by default, and the object on the other side of the relationship will be fault.

When the user clicks the cell and you display some detail view controller, you’ll take this photo and just use its property to get the big image `photo.imageData.imageData`. And only at this moment does the fault fire and is the big image loaded into memory.

Answer (score 4):

Do not store images in Core Data. They take up too much memory! If an object one of whose attributes is an image is read into memory, that image is read into memory. So if you've got 100 objects and you fetch their names, you have also loaded 100 images into memory, which can kill your app.

In Core Data, store *references* to images. Store the actual images somewhere else, e.g. on disk.

Comment: Do I do that with the allow external storage option in the xcdata file?

Comment: @Sam: I think matt means you should just store the file paths in Core Data, instead of the actual image files.